# Windows 10 no language icon on the taskbar

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, keyboard-layout, language

I've been trying to fix a keyboard switch delay problem and changed something in my registry (at that moment I had Russian and Japanese layouts), it got solved but instead I got a duplicate language problem (duplicate Japanese, to be exact), so I decided to switch to "English (United States)" layout and remove the Japanese one, but the download is just stuck at the beginning. Rebooting helped, but current language doesn't show up anymore on the taskbar (the layout switches correctly). Also I spotted that the layout in the ENG-US options is blank. [Here's a screenshot of options menu of "English (United States)" language.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOOsZ.jpg) Also I can't type in Cortana search in both languages (even paste by Ctrl+V, but pasting by RMB works fine).
**EDIT:**

1. I forgot to mention that at the very beginning I also had ENG-US layout constantly adding to my layout list (and I actually started changing my registry here, so I probably partially disabled ENG-US layout or something like that).
2. Running sfc check didn't work out for me (Destiny Integration's answer).
3. After reboot (but before running sfc check) I became able to type in Cortana search, but only in Russian.

So, how can I make the language icon show up again?

Comment: I would try and reinstall your desired keyboard layouts.

Comment: I suggest performing an in-place repair, if reinstalling the language packs and the keyboard layouts did not solve the problem, then the problem most likely is in the registry itself.  Performing an in-place repair might fix the problem.  The only other option is to run DISM, in order to repair any corruption that might exist, which I would definitely try before performing an in-place repair.  In order to perform an in-place repair, mount the appropriate Windows 10 ISO, and run Setup.exe from within Windows.  You use the same language as you used to install Windows.

Comment: I see this issue all the time. It's got nothing to do with DISM or SFC, there's nothing corrupt here, just a really annoying bug, but one that's rare enough and hard to reproduce that it's still extant. (I suspect not statistically enough people use multiple language input to get it fixed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in having `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layouts\00000409` folder in the registry renamed to `00000409-NO` (that was done to make ENG-US layout not to appear anymore). It "disabled" ENG-US layout and resulted in this strange behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I found this article on Microsoft support:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/language-bar-disappeared-from-taskbar-in-windows/c3e13a9e-880f-4b6c-ae07-c61b12d5e1d7

Hope this helps..

Comment: You should quote and cite the relevant information from your external link.